# Difficult adding up elements in a pandas DataFrame

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I'm currently having trouble adding up the rows for the following DataFrame which I have constructed for the returns for six companies' stocks:

```
def importdata(data):

returns=pd.read_excel(data) # Imports the data from Excel
returns_with_dates=returns.set_index('Dates') # Sets the Dates as the df index

return returns_with_dates
```

which outputs:

```
Out[345]: 
        Company 1  Company 2   Company 3  Company 4  Company 5  Company 6
Dates                                                                           
1997-01-02  31.087620   3.094705   24.058686  31.694404  37.162890  13.462241   
1997-01-03  31.896592   3.109631   22.423629  32.064378  37.537013  13.511706   
1997-01-06  31.723241   3.184358   18.803148  32.681000  37.038183  13.684925   
1997-01-07  31.781024   3.199380   19.503886  33.544272  37.038183  13.660193   
1997-01-08  31.607673   3.169431   19.387096  32.927650  37.537013  13.585995   
1997-01-09  31.492106   3.199380   19.737465  33.420948  37.038183  13.759214   
1997-01-10  32.589996   3.184358   19.270307  34.284219  37.661721  13.858235   
1997-01-13  32.416645   3.199380   19.153517  35.147491  38.035844  13.660193   
1997-01-14  32.301077   3.184358   19.503886  35.517465  39.407629  13.783946   
1997-01-15  32.127726   3.199380   19.387096  35.887438  38.409967  13.759214   
1997-01-16  32.532212   3.229232   19.737465  36.257412  39.282921  13.635460   
1997-01-17  33.167833   3.259180   20.087835  37.490657  39.033505  13.858235   
1997-01-20  33.456751   3.229232   20.438204  35.640789  39.657044  14.377892   
1997-01-21  33.225616   3.244158   20.671783  36.010763  40.779413  14.179940   
1997-01-22  33.110049   3.289033   21.489312  36.010763  40.654705  14.254138   
1997-01-23  32.705563   3.199380   20.905363  35.394140  40.904121  14.229405   
1997-01-24  32.127726   3.139579   20.204624  35.764114  40.405290  13.957165   
1997-01-27  32.127726   3.094705   20.204624  35.270816  40.779413  13.882968   
1997-01-28  31.781024   3.079778   20.788573  34.407544  41.153536  13.684925   
1997-01-29  32.185510   3.094705   21.138942  34.654193  41.278244  13.858235   
1997-01-30  32.647779   3.094705   21.022153  34.407544  41.652367  13.981898   
1997-01-31  32.532212   3.064757   20.204624  34.037570  42.275905  13.858235
```

For countless hours I have tried summing them up in such a way that I add up the rows from 1997-01-02 to 1997-01-08, 1997-01-09 to 1997-01-15 etc., thus adding up the first five rows, and then the following five rows. Furthermore, I seek to keep the date as an index for the 5th element, so in the case of adding up the elements from 1997-01-02 to 1997-01-08 I seek to keep 1997-01-08 as the index corresponding to the summed up element. It is worth mentioning that I have been using the five row addition as an example, but ideally I seek to add up every n rows, and then the following n rows, whilst maintaining the date in the same way said previously. I have figured out a way - shown in the code below - of doing it in array form, but I don't get to keep the dates in this situation.

```
returns=pd.read_excel(data) # Imports the data from Excel
returns_with_dates=returns.set_index('Dates') # Sets the Dates as the df index

returns_mat=returns_with_dates.as_matrix()
ndays=int(len(returns_mat)/n) # Number of "ndays" in our time-period

nday_returns=np.empty((ndays,min(np.shape(returns_mat)))) # Creates an empty array to fill
# and accommodate the n-day log-returns

for i in range(1,asset_number+1):
    for j in range(1,ndays+1):
        nday_returns[j-1,i-1]=np.sum(returns_mat[(n*j)-n:n*j,i-1])

return nday_returns
```

Is there any way of doing this but in a DataFrame context whilst maintaining the dates in the way I said before? I've been trying to do this for sooo long without any kind of success and it's really stressing me out! For some reason everyone finds Pandas extremely useful and easy to use, but I happen to find it the opposite. Any kind of help would be very much appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have the same number of missing dates you can `resample` it by the number of days you desire. Using `resample` keeps the dates in the index. You can also use the `loffset` parameter to shift the dates.

```
df.resample('7D', loffset='6D').sum()

                 Company 1  Company 2   Company 3   Company 4   Company 5  \
Dates                                                                   
1997-01-08  158.096150  15.757505  104.176445  162.911704  186.313282   
1997-01-15  160.927550  15.966856   97.052271  174.257561  190.553344   
1997-01-22  165.492461  16.250835  102.424599  181.410384  199.407588   
1997-01-29  160.927549  15.608147  103.242126  175.490807  204.520604   
1997-02-05   65.179991   6.159462   41.226777   68.445114   83.928272   

            Company 6  
Dates                  
1997-01-08  67.905060  
1997-01-15  68.820802  
1997-01-22  70.305665  
1997-01-29  69.612698  
1997-02-05  27.840133
```

Answer (score 2):

`groupby`

```
df.groupby(np.arange(len(df)) // 5).sum()
```

[image]

---

To include the date index as requested

```
g = np.arange(len(df)) // 5
i = df.index.to_series().groupby(g).last()
df.groupby(g).sum().set_index(i)
```

[image]

Comment: That's great thanks. But how do I keep the dates in the index in the way that I said above? For instance, if we sum up the elements from 1997-01-02 to 1997-01-08, how can I keep the index of the new summed up element be 1997-01-09? And so on.

Comment: Thank you so much! Worked perfectly.